# How can I add column to an existing custom table in MODX database?

Tags: pdo, modx, modx-revolution

I have a custom table in MODX database set up and working, thanks to this article:
http://bobsguides.com/custom-db-tables.html
and now I need to add new column to this existing table. How can I do this the "MODX way"? Or do I have to create the component from scratch again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add the new column to the database, then update your xml schema and map files to include the new column metadata. If you have a build script you could simply run it again after amending the schema to regenerate the map files.

I could be more specific if you paste in your existing schema and description of the column you want to add.

Comment: Thanks okyanet, what I did is I removed the schema, added the new column and then run the Bob's script again and it works perfect now.
There is also some information at: http://forums.modx.com/thread/84873/how-can-i-add-column-to-an-existing-custom-table-in-modx-database#dis-post-467991 where I've started a thread about it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe MigxDB plugin (part of migx plugin) sets up a utility under manager page to just do that. 
Install migx as instructed (you need to do an extra step to set it up so read the instruction)
load your modified schema in midx-package manager and do 'parse schema' and then 'add field'.
Make sure you have package name and pre-fix specified when loading your schema. modx forum has a dedicated section for migx if you need further clarification.